# awscli list tags in all services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

is there a way to list/describe all the tags in all the services in an aws environment with one command?
E.g. If I wanted to list the tags in ec2 instances, I can do this `aws ec2 describe-tags` and can see all the tags. Now if I wanted to view, say, eks tags I'd have to do something like `aws eks list-tags-for-resource ...` or something similar. So my question is if there is a "magic" where I could do `aws * describe-tags` and see all the tags in all services, instead of going one by one for each service like so: `aws <service name> <command to describe/list tags>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use : [aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html)

**From the docs:**

> Returns all the tagged or previously tagged resources that are located
>   in the specified Region for the AWS account.

**Usage:**

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "ResourceTagMappingList": [
        {
            "ResourceARN": " arn:aws:inspector:us-west-2:123456789012:target/0-nvgVhaxX/template/0-7sbz2Kz0",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Environment",
                    "Value": "Production"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```